# Add view to admin menu to filter for specific criteria ( If post is child of specific Parent )

Tags: posts, filters, admin, views

```
add_filter('views_edit-page','addFilter');

function addFilter($views) {

         global $wp_query;

         $query = array(
             'post_type'   => 'page',
             'post_status' => 'publish',
             'post_parent' => 2795,
         );

         $result = new WP_Query($query);


         $class = ($_GET['post_parent'] == 2795) ? ' class="current"' : '';
         $views['publish_f'] = sprintf(__("<a href='%s'". $class .">". 'Post Parent = 2795' ." <span class='count'>(%d)</span></a>", 'brookdale' ), admin_url('edit.php?post_type=page&post_parent=2795'), $result->found_posts);

         return $views;

}
```

I want to create filter for my Admin panel "Pages" tab that only shows pages that are children or grand-children or great-grand-children of the parent post. I currently have the tab showing, but when I click the filter it does not load the pages into the word press pages list. I have been trying to find documentation on this specific function for wordpress but it's a bit difficult to explain correctly in a google search.

[image: Shows the tab name, but the functionality does not work correctly]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "load the pages" via the [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) action, like so:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_admin_pre_get_posts' );
function my_admin_pre_get_posts( $q ) {
  // Check whether the filter was clicked.
  if ( isset( $_GET['post_parent'] ) ) {
    $screen = is_admin() ? get_current_screen() : null;

    // And that it's the edit pages page.
    if ( $screen && 'edit-page' === $screen->id ) {
      $post_parent = (int) $_GET['post_parent'];
      $q->set( 'post_parent', $post_parent );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to include an additional conditional, one that also checks to see if the posts grand-parent is 2795 before displaying, how would I go about this?

Comment: You can use the `post_parent__in` parameter, which is a list (array) of post parent IDs. So if for example: great-grandparent = `1234`, grandparent = `3456`, parent = `5678`; you can use `$q->set( 'post_parent__in', array( 1234, 3456, 5678 ) );` to query for posts whose `post_parent` is one of the specified post IDs. Let me know if you need a sample code.